# Getting error in method decorator TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

Im learning decorators in typescript, os ive been experimenting with [method decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators).
Trying to get a grasp on what is being passed as arguments to the decorator I made a simple check with `instanceof` where I got the error:

> TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

This error is produced by the decorator function in the following example:

```js
export function log(
  target: any, /* What is this? */
  propertyKey: string /* The name of the method */,
  descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) {
  console.log(`target instanceof Some -> `, target instanceof Someone); // ERROR 
}

class Someone {
  constructor(public name: string) {}

  @log
  hello() {
    console.log(`Hello! My name is ${this.name}`);
  }
}

const inst = new Someone("Riksan");
inst.hello();
```

Comment: I added an answer to you question.  Could you notify if it is satisfactory?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @CraigHicks , but the intention is not to get rid of the error. I can handle that. The question is why the error.
TBH Im struggling to find a decent reason for decorators to exist at all except to make some folks comming from Java and C# feel more confortable

Comment: It has been said - <i>Decorators can be used to simplify code structure, validate input, optimize performance, and implement aspect-oriented programming patterns</i>.  Like all features though, using them just because they are there, even if they aren't immediately needed at all, is a waste of time.

Comment: This runs: [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: @Hairi _"Im struggling to find a decent reason for decorators to exist at all"_ What about patterns like marking certain class members; e.g., for serialization or something? Or easily wrapping functions with debug code (logging, timing, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function log(originalMethod: any, _context: any) {

    function replacementMethod(this: any, ...args: any[]) {
        console.log("LOG: Entering method.")
        const result = originalMethod.call(this, ...args);
        console.log("LOG: Exiting method.")
        return result;
    }

    return replacementMethod;
}
```

See [this documentation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#decorators)

[Working example in TypescriptPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgDYIOYYKYBMCy2MAFgrgBQIBOcGcEAhqoSWQFzIMQCeANMgH0oSGNgAeMDl24BKZAG9gwZCuTho8JMirYADqgZRsAW2wQYLUhRJwAzlJ78AdC4ZUM9zjwDaAXTmKqkHIwhC2CKjYTugY5ABEADIA8gDiHACi5tg0EBjIpqy4TnEyysEqobYw2ti2YKjVALzI1LT0TJZkTlBMqOQ2ts6u7rYyANxl5ZURUTHxyWnI6WJw8Ln5RFbFpeUqOjBgVCg6dQ0TQQC+SkH7h8d6Bkam5p24E1dKUAa2tsgAyghTEhsAoypUYFQwLBqORdGAAEaoOBQZCMUwcKo5DABD4qAACMRwBE2ZDKxGwqHQ5ACkxCSHCkWimHIAAMABIU9AAQmQ+G4qIYpmQdmQABJ5AMnGjsBcWeMylcPuDhWEmqjsAB3f6A7DA+IAJTgAGtbFwShN6FUnOTKQhqRMgA)